# Detect if an event is set from another class

Tags: c#

I understand that invoking an event from another class would make practically no sense.

But then to make some optimizations I noticed that I could improve performance if an event is not set.

Sadly C# does not allows me to do this

```
public class A
{
    public event Action Event;

    public bool IsEventSet { return Event != null; }
}

main 
{
   var a = new A();
   var isSet = a.Event == null; //why is this not allowed! I can not understand
   isSet = a.IsEventSet; //this seems like a hack to me!
}
```

I hope I am clear enough and there is a reason for this

is there a reason for this?

Thanks!

Comment: @phoog I know, I thought I was clear enough, I edited that

Comment: Ah, okay, after your edit it makes more sense.  I'm sure this is a duplicate but I don't have time right now to search for the answer.  If I recall correctly Eric Lippert wrote a long answer a few years ago discussing why the C# team chose the event pattern they chose.

Comment: I will look for it then, I could not found it

Comment: From outside of the class, you can only += or -= event. What's the reason you don't use `a.IsEventSet`?

Comment: just a design question, I feel like it is a hack

Comment: IIRC the discussion was about subscribing to the event rather than checking whether it's been subscribed to, but the basic issue is the same: why is the treatment of the event different in the declaring class compared to other classes?

Comment: I recommend you read more about Events (how they work and how we can use them)...  http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx

Comment: [This search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A88656+event) also turns up at least a couple of interesting answers from Jon Skeet.

Comment: In this way you won't mess up with the event handler that subscribed. You can only touch the part it opens to you.

Comment: @phoog That helps a lot I will take a read there, maybe I found why they decided this design.

Comment: @bto.rdz, i believe this should work var isSet = (a.Event == null);

Comment: @Dr.Stitch me too, and it does not, that is the question!

Comment: @bto.rdz, had you put the bool isSet = (a.Event == null);?

Comment: what's your endgame?

Comment: @DanielA.White I feel bad because c# denies me this, that is all, I just thought there was a reason for this, but I think there is not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var isSet = a.Event == null; //why is this not allowed! I can not understand
```

Why is it not allowed? Because it is an `event`, not a `delegate`.

In c#, an `event` is just a delegate with constraints.

I had been coding c# for some years before I realised that you can treat a delegate like an event. Specifically, you can attach and detach any number of subscribers to one delegate.

The following code demonstrates this:

```
using System;

public class A
{
    public event Action Event;

    // You could just use System.Action, but I want the example to be clear
    public delegate void HandlerDelegateType();

    public HandlerDelegateType PublicDelegate;


    public void Fire()
    {
        if(PublicDelegate != null)
        {
            PublicDelegate();
        }
    }
}

public static class MainClass
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();

        if(a.PublicDelegate == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a.PublicDelegate is null");
        }

        a.PublicDelegate += () => { Console.WriteLine("First handler fired!"); };
        a.PublicDelegate += () => { Console.WriteLine("Second handler fired!"); };


        a.Fire();

        if(a.PublicDelegate != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a.PublicDelegate is not null");
        }


        return 0;
    }
}
```

The log output is

> a.PublicDelegate is null
>
> First handler fired!
>
> Second handler fired!
>
> a.PublicDelegate is not null

By using the `event` keyword, you are explicitly limiting the way it can be used.

Limiting the way that a member can be accessed is a key facet of object oriented design. It allows you, the designer, to be opinionated about how your class will be used. While c# gives you this functionality, you can happily disagree with it and expose a delegate instead of an event.

---

And now I will admit that the phrase "just a delegate with constraints" is an oversimplification. 
You can actually expose an event as a public interface to an underlying delegate, like so:

```
private HandlerDelegateType _privateDelegate;

public event HandlerDelegateType PublicEvent
{
    add
    {
        _privateDelegate += value;

    }
    remove
    {
        _privateDelegate-= value;
        if(_privateDelegate == null)
        {
            // Can perform some other action here
            // For example, unsubscribe from a second event source
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just needed to notice if there was a handler attached to the event form another class, I think there is no a practical way for this

Comment: @bto.rdz - My opinion: your `a.IsEventSet` solution is the best solution

Comment: `delegate` inherits `MultiCastDelegate`. And "A MulticastDelegate has a linked list of delegates, called an invocation list ... the delegates in the invocation list are called synchronously in the order in which they appear"  P.S. **so much for the maxim that the order of event handlers fire is not guaranteed.**

Answer (score 1):

The reason C# doesn't allow you to do this is because there's a whole lot of syntactic sugar helping you out here.  Events in C# are really more closely related to properties and the short form that you usually use is like an auto-property.  You're actually letting the compiler do a lot of work for you.

Perhaps it would help to see the full declaration of an event that the compiler generates for you.  What I have below is roughly equivalent to what the compiler generates.

```
public class A
{
    public event Action Event
    {
        add
        {
            mEventBackingField = (Action) Delegate.Combine( mEventBackingField, value );
        }
        remove
        {
            mEventBackingField = (Action) Delegate.Remove( mEventBackingField, value );
        }
    }

    private Action mEventBackingField;
}
```

I've left out some other junk the compiler throws in there for thread safety, but this is the general gist of what's going on when you write `public event Action Event;`.  When you refer to `Event` within the class, the compiler basically replaces it with a reference to the backing field for that event.  That allows you to do the null checks and to raise the event from within the class.

From outside the class the only thing that's actually visible are the `add` and `remove` methods on the event.  There's no way to actually see the underlying delegate.  This is a good thing.

Why?  Well if you were allowed to get at the underlying delegate value outside the class, you'd be able to raise the event from outside the class!  Anyone anywhere could get ahold of that event and invoke the registered delegates.  That'd be a maintenance nightmare.

But what if you actually want to allow that sort of thing to happen?  Well, in that case you don't want an event, you want a property:

```
public class A
{
    public Action Event { get; set; }
}
```